# Not able to create a simple RDD - Parallelized Collections in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to create an rdd of a collection and eventually store that in a dataframe that I can write back into a csv.

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{
  StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

object Main extends Serializable {

  class Input_Class extends Serializable {
    var name: String = "";
    var age: String = "";
    var gender: String = "";

    def setter(src: Row) {
      var row = src.toSeq
      var i = 0;
      name = row(i).toString;
      i += 1;
      age = row(i).toString;
      i += 1;
      gender = row(i).toString;
    }

    def printing(row: Row) {
        println(name, age, gender)
    }
  }

  class Output_Class extends Serializable {
    var name: String = "";
    var age: Int = 0;
    var gender: String = "";
    var marks: Int = 0;
    def writer(){
      val data = Array(name,age,gender,marks)
      val distData = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
      distData.collect().foreach(println)
    }
  }

  class Manager extends Serializable {
    var inputObj = new Input_Class();
    var outputObj = new Output_Class();

    def inputSetter(src: Row) = {
        inputObj.setter(src);
    }

    def transformation(){
        outputObj.age = inputObj.age.toInt;
        outputObj.name = inputObj.name;
        outputObj.gender = inputObj.gender;
        outputObj.marks = 100;
        outputwriter();
    }

    def outputwriter(){
        outputObj.writer();
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("App").config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.read.csv("/Users/kagarwa9/Desktop/data.csv ");
    df.rdd.map(row => {
      var ManagerObj = new Manager();
      ManagerObj.inputSetter(row)
      ManagerObj.transformation();
    }).collect();
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

I need to create the classes for the input and output, it is a business need. The issue is arising in the writer method of the Output Class.

The error that I am getting is as follows:

```
20/06/04 16:45:55 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect.
20/06/04 16:45:58 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Main$Output_Class.writer(Test.scala:60)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Main$Manager.outputwriter(Test.scala:85)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Main$Manager.transformation(Test.scala:80)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Main$.$anonfun$main$1(Test.scala:96)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Main$.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(Test.scala:94)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:311)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:305)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:305)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:292)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:286)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
20/06/04 16:45:58 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Main$Output_Class.writer(Test.scala:60)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Main$Manager.outputwriter(Test.scala:85)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Main$Manager.transformation(Test.scala:80)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Main$.$anonfun$main$1(Test.scala:96)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Main$.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(Test.scala:94)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:311)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:305)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:305)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:292)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:286)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

20/06/04 16:45:58 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Main$Output_Class.writer(Test.scala:60)
        at Main$Manager.outputwriter(Test.scala:85)
        at Main$Manager.transformation(Test.scala:80)
        at Main$.$anonfun$main$1(Test.scala:96)
        at Main$.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(Test.scala:94)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:311)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:305)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:305)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:292)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:286)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:274)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:945)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
  at Main$.main(Test.scala:94)
  ... 51 elided
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at Main$Output_Class.writer(Test.scala:60)
  at Main$Manager.outputwriter(Test.scala:85)
  at Main$Manager.transformation(Test.scala:80)
  at Main$.$anonfun$main$1(Test.scala:96)
  at Main$.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(Test.scala:94)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
  at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
  at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
  at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:311)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1429)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:305)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:305)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1429)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:292)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:286)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1429)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:945)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2101)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please help me out here I am a newbie and don't have much experience on this.

Comment: You are doing very weird things in your code. Your classes for data transformation don´t need to write nor any kind of writing operations.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 actually most of the code here is generated by jinja templating so cannot modify that.  I understand that this is not very close to a spark code but this is what the business requirement is for now. Please see if you can help me out in simply writing the output class datamembers as a spark dataframe into a csv.

This is a prototype/testing code.

Comment: I have made a couple of changes in the code as suggested by @Rayan Rai in his answer. Please check if you guys can sort this one out for me. Thanks 

Comment: you misunderstand the whole concept of Spark ... your initial data is already parallelized, i.e. it is already a Spark RDD. But in your `transform` method you again try to parallelize data - that's weird and also it's impossible in Spark to use the Spark context in a Spark function. Look at your code, in the `map` method you do again `park.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
      distData.collect().foreach(println)` - why? All you want is to return a plain Scala String

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser for the input, I am going to use apache-ignite table and write down the transformed data (data members of the Output Class) as single rows in the table. So should I do that in the main method? or will the map method somehow return me a dataframe? 
Sorry if I am making no sense, I am a total newbie to this and dont have much help on spark. Really appreciate everyones input, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass spark context inside rdd map function, like you do in

```
.map(row => {
        ...
        ManagerObj.transformation(spark);
    })
```

Instead, if you need to save your data, first do the transformation, and then collect it, or save to some storage.

Also, function inside `df.map` is being executed on the worker nodes, not on the driver, so `ManagerObj` instance you've created also won't be available there.

Comment: Okay, I tried testing the code again by making the necessary changes still getting the same error.

Comment: You need to just take your `transformation` function, make it so it transforms one Row into the other (if you need to add columns, or change some values), and then collect `df` after this transformation function.

Comment: I have edited the code in the question as per your suggestions (as far as I understood). I can bring the Manager Class instance creation inside the map method,  I hope that helps. I have also removed the passing of spark object. Please check once again and let me know what else can be an issue here coz I am still getting the same error. Thanks :)

Comment: @KrishnaAgarwal Thanks for the update, but you're still using `spark` instance inside your `Output_Class.writer` method, `val distData = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)`. This data is already parallelized, and running on Spark workers, so spark context won't be available there.

Comment: Okay, So from the Outputclass.writer function I should return a concatenated string of all its data members and get it in the main method? Would I be able to accumulate all the returned strings from the output class into a single dataframe? Coz I need to write it into an apache-ignite table later on..